# R - Plot 2 trend-lines on same plot and change line length

Tags: r, plot, trendline

I have a dataset with actual and modelled values. I have split the dataset into two periods Jan 2003- Dec 2006 and Jan 2007- Dec 2012 and plotted trend lines - there are two trends lines for actual values (for 2 time periods) and 2 for modelled. I have attached a picture - I want to control the length of the lines so that they start and stop at the right time - but I cannot figure this out! I have attached the code that I have managed so far - I'm still fairly new.Also attached a picture in case the above is not clear. Thanks!

I'm not sure if there is a way I could put a vertical line at 2007 (Jan) and use this line as the reference to start and stop the respective lines?

```
plot(NULL, type="n", xlim=x.limit, ylim=c(-30, 30), xlab="Year", ylab="Equivalent Water     Depth (cm)", axes=F, cex.lab=0.9)

box(lwd=1.5)
abline(h=0, col="gray50", lty=1, lwd=1)
axis(1, seq(2003, 2013, 1), cex.axis=0.7)
axis(2, seq(-40, 40, 10), las=1, cex.axis=0.7, tck=-0.03)
minor.tick(nx=4, ny=0, tick.ratio=0.5)
lines(tws.avg.VNB[,2] ~ tws.avg.VNB[,1], type="l", lwd=2, col=1) 

tws.slope1 <- round(as.vector(coef(lm(SPLIT.1.ALL.VNB[,2] ~ SPLIT.1.ALL.VNB[,1]))[2]), 2)
tws.sdev1 <- round(as.vector(coef(summary(lm(SPLIT.1.ALL.VNB[,2] ~ SPLIT.1.ALL.VNB[,1])))[, "Std. Error"][2]), 2)
mtext(paste("GRACE Trend: 2003-2007 (cm/yr): ", tws.slope1, "±", tws.sdev1, sep=""), cex=0.5, side=1, line=-1.8, adj=0.15)
abline(lm(SPLIT.1.ALL.VNB[,2] ~ SPLIT.1.ALL.VNB[,1]), lwd=2, lty=2, col="deepskyblue")

tws.slope2 <- round(as.vector(coef(lm(SPLIT.2.ALL.VNB[,2] ~ SPLIT.2.ALL.VNB[,1]))[2]), 2)
tws.sdev2 <- round(as.vector(coef(summary(lm(SPLIT.2.ALL.VNB[,2] ~ SPLIT.2.ALL.VNB[,1])))[, "Std. Error"][2]), 2)
mtext(paste("GRACE Trend: 2007-2012 (cm/yr): ", tws.slope2, "±", tws.sdev2, sep=""), cex=0.5, side=1, line=-1.1, adj=0.15)
abline(lm(SPLIT.2.ALL.VNB[,2] ~ SPLIT.2.ALL.VNB[,1]), lwd=2, lty=2, col="deepskyblue")
lines(VNB.OBS.TWS[,1] ~ tws.avg.VNB[,1], type="l", lwd=2, col="red")

tws.slope3 <- round(as.vector(coef(lm(SPLIT.1.ALL.VNB[,6] ~ SPLIT.1.ALL.VNB[,1]))[2]), 2)
tws.sdev3 <- round(as.vector(coef(summary(lm(SPLIT.1.ALL.VNB[,6] ~ SPLIT.1.ALL.VNB[,1])))[, "Std. Error"][2]), 2)
mtext(paste("OBSERVED Trend: 2003-2007 (cm/yr): ", tws.slope3, "±", tws.sdev3, sep=""), cex=0.5, side=1, line=-1.8, adj=0.85)
abline(lm(SPLIT.1.ALL.VNB[,6] ~ SPLIT.1.ALL.VNB[,1]), lwd=2, lty=2, col="forestgreen")

tws.slope4 <- round(as.vector(coef(lm(SPLIT.2.ALL.VNB[,6] ~ SPLIT.2.ALL.VNB[,1]))[2]), 2)
tws.sdev4 <- round(as.vector(coef(summary(lm(SPLIT.2.ALL.VNB[,6] ~ SPLIT.2.ALL.VNB[,1])))[, "Std. Error"][2]), 2)
mtext(paste("OBSERVED Trend: 2007-2012 (cm/yr): ", tws.slope4, "±", tws.sdev4, sep=""), cex=0.5, side=1, line=-1.1, adj=0.85)
abline(lm(SPLIT.2.ALL.VNB[,6] ~ SPLIT.2.ALL.VNB[,1]), lwd=2, lty=2, col="forestgreen")

legend("bottomright", "(a)", bty="n", cex=0.8) 
legend("top", legend=expression(Delta~TWS~(GRACE), GRACE~TREND, Delta~TWS~(OBSERVED), OBSERVED~TREND),
   lty=c(1,4,1,4), lwd=c(2,2,2,2), col=c(1,"deepskyblue","red","forestgreen"),
   bty="n", horiz=T, cex=0.6)
```

[image: The code is for the top plot!]

Answer (score 0):

Look into the package `zoo`. Among many other features, it implements a new class specifically for time series that keeps track of the time base, and the `plot.zoo` method makes use of it. As a very, very minimal example, you can try something like a following:

```
a <- zoo(rnorm(5), 1:5)
b <- zoo(rpois(5, 1), 1:5)
plot(cbind(a, b))
```

A base R solution is also pretty simple:

```
a <- rnorm(5)
b <- rpois(5, 1)
plot(a ~ 1:5, xlim = c(0, 10))
points(b ~ 6:10)
```

Comment: Thank you @ssdecontrol - I will give this a try - I was trying to use segments but to no avail!

Comment: Struggling to figure out the above in context of my plot code!

Comment: I don't think so - I have two datasets covering 2003-2012. I have split these datasets into two time periods - Jan 2003 to Dec 2006 and Jan 2007 to Dec 2012 and have drawn trend lines for each period. abline() function plots continuous lines. I want my trend lines for 2003-2006 to be shown for that time period only and the same for 2007-2012. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes I understand now. You'll want to use the `segments` function then.